# PowerShell net use not showing

Tags: powershell

I wonder if it's not possible to show a list of which network drives are connected on a specific PC when I login through `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName []`?

Whenever I enter a PC successfully and type `net use` it says:

> New connections will be remembered. There are no entries in the list.

I don't know if i'm a newbie here - but there should be at least 3-4 network drives shown.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use get-psdrive, granted you will get more drives than the one I suppose you need, but without more information that's all I can say...